# Is there any way to add "code split line" in VS2008 editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, editor

I am just considering if there is anyway to make a "comment-like" split lines in VS code editor; The motivation is when source code file gets longer, and more function definition are added in source code, so that source code turns to be huge mess and not easy to read. So in order to improve readability, using some comment to group codes is necessary.

I want to insert split line within the source code, such as

```
/*
** <Split Line 1> This section is to define some local vars
*/

int a;
int b;

/*
** <Split Line 1>  Then some function definition
*/
void fun1(){...}
void fun2(){...}
```

And it's not that convenient to input 
 `/*......*/`
 as a break, so I am asking for if there is a more **elegant** and **built-in** way in VS Editor (I am using Visual Studio 2008). It should be kinda similar to the function of `///` mark or '#-commands' in VS.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `Region`s are what your looking for

```
#Region Local vars
    int a;
    int b;
#EndRegion
```

This allows you to collapse the code section using the `-` icon next to the line numbers.

Comment: Yes that's it!!! thank you! but in VS 2008 seems like the correct syntax should be #regin .... #endregion

Comment: The syntax for C# is `#region` ... `#endregion`. The syntax for VB.NET is `#Region` ... `#End Region`. The syntax for C++ is `#pragma region` ... `#pragma endregion`. You need to specify a language; VS 2008 supports a whole bunch of 'em.